# How to list values using ng-repeat using AngularJS and JsonResult ASP.NET MVC

Tags: json, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to render a list from my JsonResult Controller. It's ok, I receive data in my Angular service, but a in trouble to render it in a list using ng-repeat. It´s renders a big empty list. 
When the data is not a list, it´s works.

Angular.
[Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDzWj.png)

```
var app = angular.module('FileApp', []);        
app.service('ngFileService', function ($http) {        
  this.getFileByFileCode = function (fileCodigo) {
    var response = $http.get("/Files/GetFile?fileCodigo=" + fileCodigo);
    return response;
  };

});

app.controller('ngFileController', function ($scope, ngFileService) {                
  $scope.filterFileCode = "";

  $scope.getFilteredFile = function () {
    var promise = ngFileService.getFileByFileCode($scope.filterFileCode);
    promise.then(function (resp) {
      $scope.File = resp.data;       
      $scope.Message = "Call is Completed Successfully";
    }, function (err) {
      $scope.Message = "Call Failed " + err.status;
    });
  };
});
```

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEwVQ.png)

```
        <tr>
          <td>Enter Search Value:</td>
          <td><input type="text" ng-model="filterFileCode" class="form- 
         control" ng-change="getFilteredFile()" /></td>
        </tr>
      <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Documentos Gerais File</th>
            <th></th>
            <th>CTB</th>
            <th>COM</th>
            <th>Site</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="f in File">
            <td>Documentos</td>
            <td>{{f.FileCTB}}</td>
            <td>{{f.FileCOM}}</td>
            <td>{{f.FileSite}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

[Erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwnpB.png)

I expect to render a list of boolens values.

```
**DataCriacao: "/Date(-62135596800000)/"
DataFim: "06/07/2018"
DataInicio: "26/06/2018"
DescricaoServico: null
FileCOM: (2) [true, false]
FileCTB: (2) [false, false]
FileCodigo: 190562
FileCodigoId: 0
FileCodigoNv: null
FileMimeType: null
FileSite: (2) [false, false]**
```

[SOLVED]
I find de solution making the above solution:

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Documentos</td>
    <td>Comandos</td>
    <td><span ng-repeat="(key, value) in File.FileCTB track by $index"> 
         {{value}}</span></td>
    <td><span ng-repeat="(key, value) in File.FileCOM track by $index"> 
         {{value}}</span></td>
    <td><span ng-repeat="(key, value) in File.FileSite track by $index"> 
         {{value}}</span></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: can you include json returned from your controller in your question please.

Comment: I have it in my [link](https://imgur.com/77POUPN)

Comment: Please don't add "solved" or similar phrases to your question when you've solved the problem. If someone gave you an answer, [accept it](/help/someone-answers). If you found a solution on your own, [post an answer](/help/self-answer) (you can also accept your own answer after two days). Accepting answers is also the way to show a question has been solved - editing "solved" into the question is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem storing in a viewModel object all date below:

```
DataCriacao: "/Date(-62135596800000)/"
DataFim: "06/07/2018"
DataInicio: "26/06/2018"
DescricaoServico: null
FileCOM: (2) [true, false]
FileCTB: (2) [false, false]
FileCodigo: 190562
FileCodigoId: 0
FileCodigoNv: null
FileMimeType: null
FileSite: (2) [false, false]
```

So, I can iterate only in the attribute that is collections ou array.